# High voltage current source improvements

Tags: analog, current-source

Here is an old school MOSFET based audio amplifier. I unfortunately do not remember the source of this circuit.

The upper rail voltage can be few hundred volts (MOSFET replaced and a few components.)

The red marked area is a constant current source. VR2 is adjusted to until a bias current flows through the power MOSFETs and T4 provides a temperature compensation.

Whilst this circuit works, the method of the constant current source isn't great as it is relatively sensitive in adjustment, not very stable in temperature and requires manual adjustment.

I was looking to improve this circuit, but the high voltage rails makes the use of an op-amp based solution difficult. So far I haven't found any good solution to this problem.

[image]

Comment: Use a simple (or more complicated, Wilson) "Widlar" current source. Just choose "high voltage" (Vce max > 100 V) PNP BJT.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the two transistors T4 and T5 are in contact with each other, (preferably glued or clamped), to keep the two devices at similar temperatures. That will help their \$V_{BE}\$ to stay together.

Failing that, do you have any reason why you can't make a crude low voltage regulator with a zener diode and resistor, and use that to power an op-amp?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEIJcD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Choose R1 to pass at least the worst-case supply current needed by the opamp, plus a smidgen for its output. The TLC2272 here needs at most 3mA. R1 will get a bit warm.

The voltage at the opamp's non-inverting input should be far more stable, since D1 won't get hot, like T5 does in the original circuit.

It might be easier to move the potentiometer adjustment to the opamp's input, and replace VR1 and R4 with a fixed resistance. That's probably how I would have designed it, if there was no need to integrate this into an existing circuit.